# Transfer files to vm

Tags: python, virtualbox

I'm currently working on a script that sends files from Win10 to Oracle vm running Win10 as well.

I have to keep a high security protocol and to not exceed the limits of the script, there is no option doing things manually.

I'm really new to this and not familiar with the different methods, but for now I'm trying to transfer the files using shared folders:

```
    self.vbox = virtualbox.VirtualBox()

    # The virtual box of the current executor.
    self.machine = self.vbox.find_machine("Windows 10")

    self.session = self.machine.create_session()

    # Create a shared folder. With this folder the client transfers the files of the current request which have
    # received from the server to its virtual machine.
    self.shared_folder_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/Requests To Execute/"

    # Before any change or modification on the vm, the session must be locked using mutex, in order to make sure
    # that the vm won't be changed by one process while another one isn't aware.
    self.machine.lock_machine(self.session, virtualbox.LockType())
    self.mutable = self.session.getMachine()
    self.mutable.create_shared_folder("Requests", self.shared_folder_dir, True, True)
    self.mutable.saveSettings()
    self.session.unlockMachine()
```

I couldn't figure how I can supply a LockType as an argument to create_shared_folder. Anyway, if anyone has a better idea about how to transfer the files it will be great also.